# Android Finding Fragment TextView from Parent Class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

*I've seen similar questions to mine here, but none of the solutions have helped (I've tried many).*

So I have a fragment, which I'm create an instance of both in my main activity and in another activity. The fragment has methods to change various TextViews, and everything works great when I call those methods from my main activity. However, when I try to do the same in my other activity, I keep getting a null pointer exception that the textView isn't found. Here is the relevant code:

activity where it doesn't work:

```
TextView p1n;
TextView p2n;
TextView p1s;
TextView p2s;

ScoreFragment SF;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tic_tac_toe);

    SF = new ScoreFragment();

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.frag_frame_ttt, SF);
    ft.commit();

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    Log.d(jl, intent.getStringExtra(P1_NAME_KEY));
    if (intent != null) {
        if (intent.getStringExtra(P1_NAME_KEY) != null && p1n != null) {
            SF.setp1name(intent.getStringExtra(P1_NAME_KEY));
        }
        if (intent.getStringExtra(P2_NAME_KEY) != null && p2n != null) {
            SF.setp2name(intent.getStringExtra(P2_NAME_KEY));

        }
        if (p1s != null) {
            SF.setp1score(intent.getIntExtra(P1_SCORE_KEY, 0));

        }
        if (p2s != null) {
            SF.setp2score(intent.getIntExtra(P2_SCORE_KEY, 0));
        }
        Log.d(jl, Integer.toString(intent.getIntExtra(P2_SCORE_KEY, 0)));
    }
```

Since p1n, p2n, p1s, and p2s are always null, nothing happens.

Here is the frame layout i'm trying to put the fragment in,

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/frag_frame_ttt"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"

    />
```

and here is my relevant fragment code:

```
...
TextView p1name;
TextView p2name;
TextView p1score;
TextView p2score;
...

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_score, container, false);
    p1name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.p1_name);
    p2name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.p2_name);
    p1score = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.p1_score);
    p2score = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.p2_score);
    Log.d(jl, "onCreateView successful");

    return v;
}

public void setp1name(String name) {
    p1name.setText(name);
}
public void setp2name(String name) {
    p2name.setText(name);
}
public void setp1score(int score) {
    p1score.setText(Integer.toString(score));
}
public void setp2score(int score) {
    p2score.setText(Integer.toString(score));
}
```

and the relevant fragment xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Player 1"
            android:id="@+id/p1_name"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" : " />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:id="@+id/p1_score"/>



    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Player 2"
            android:id="@+id/p2_name"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" : " />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:id="@+id/p2_score"/>



    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

So after doing some debugging I am quite certain that the issue has to do with the findViewById method in onCreateView() not finding anything, but I've tried moving where I findViewById (such as in each method where the text is being set), but it still hasn't worked.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is `R`? Where is it declared and initialized?

Comment: All I know about R is it's a special auto-generated android class that allows you to reference your xml constants in your java code.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

Aside from my stupid bug in my activity where I only set the text if the textview variables (the ones I never set) aren't null...

I had to move all of the code pertaining to my fragment (except for the initialize and the add / commit) from onCreate to onStart. Guess I was trying to preform actions on these textviews before the fragment actually inflated(? sorry I'm new to android, this may be incorrect).